# How to save list of edittext content changes?

Tags: android

I want to restore previous text content on pressing undo button. With code below I can see what how did String changed, save new string to stack. For restore I just pop stack to get previous text. However that approach does not consider any changes in spannable. How to track what was changed be it either text or its styling or both?

```
Stack<String> save = new Stack<>();


  Runnable saveRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
      if (tvValueDesc != null) {
        String text = tvValueDesc.getText().toString();
        if (save.isEmpty()) save.push(text);
        if (!save.peek().equals(text)) save.push(text);
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
      }
    }
  };

@OnClick(R.id.btn_undo) void restore() {
    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);

    if (!save.empty()) save.pop();
    if (!save.empty()) {
      tvValueDesc.setText(save.peek());
    } else {
      tvValueDesc.setText(null);
    }
    handler.postDelayed(saveRunnable, 1000);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save text with spannable we should take charsequence from spannable, not the string

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to create Custom textPojo that includes all text propertices which you want to store ,like typeFace, text,Text Style, text size, text color , Text Alignment etc,

And When you store text while pressing button store all this information into TextPojo and maintain  TextPojo stack rather maintaining single String .